# Azure AD - SAML Single Logout - Unsupported binding HTTP-POST

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0

I am integrating a SAML Service Provider with MS AAD and I have found an issue with Single Logout. My Service Provider only supports logout binding "HTTP-POST". And it seems that AAD only supports logout binding "HTTP-Redirect". I think so based on the SAML metadata I got from AAD - this is the only SingleLogoutService element I can see:

```
<SingleLogoutService
    Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
    Location="https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/saml2" />
```

Is it really the only supported SLO binding or is it possible to switch other bindings on somehow? I would especially like HTTP-POST.

If it's the only one, are there any plans to support other binding in the near future (let's say in 6 months)?

Comment: did you find any workaround for this? I too have the same issue and there's an open issue on passport-saml GitHub page.

Comment: Hi Ben, it's hard to say after such a long time, I think we finally found a way how to implement HTTP-Redirect in our service provider. But try looking at AAD again, AAD in 2022 may be more powerful that AAD in 2018. I have not used it since then, sorry.