# SingleLogoutService in metadata

Tags: azure-active-directory

I was told that Tableau server requires these 2 SingleLogoutService elements below that are not in the SAML metadata from Azure AD. If I add these, it works.

Is it supported to manually add these?
Is there a plan to add these in the future to the metadata on AAD?

```
<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://login.microsoftonline.com/f4094948-32fb-4c4b-b659-63b99f22a08d/saml2" />
<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://login.microsoftonline.com/f4094948-32fb-4c4b-b659-63b99f22a08d/saml2" />
```

Comment: Simlar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178430/azure-ad-saml-single-logout-unsupported-binding-http-post

Answer (score 0):

WE never heard this as a requirement from the Tableau side. Can you please specify that you are using Tableau server or cloud version? If this is server then which version of it?

You can add more Logout URLs int he metadata as you need but note that Azure AD does not support SOAP biding or Redirect binding for SAML Logout. Only POST biding is supported.