# Azure AD SSO SingleLogoutService doesn't have POST binding in Federation metadata

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito

When tried to integrate a SP(Cognito) with IdP (Azure AD) through SAML federation,

Azure AD SSO SingleLogoutService doesn't have POST binding in the federation metadata. It does only have `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect`.

What should we do to add `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST` in the metadata. I've went through [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-out-saml-protocol) and didn't find one.

Whereas I've tried to integrate ADFS, ADFS metadata have both HTTP-Redirect and HTTP-POST. The SAML Logout Response from IdP is sent to SP as POST and works perfectly.

The login flow works pretty straight and has no problems at all. Whereas with Logout, IdP accepts SAML Logout Request and provides the SAML Logout Response through GET endpoint which should be a POST binding endpoint that SP accepts.

Is the absence of `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST` binding in SingleLogoutService disrupts the logout?

Does Azure support only GET for `SingleLogoutService`? Azure docs doesn't have any reference regarding the binding it supports for Logout.

Answer (score 2):

I think Azure AD only supports HTTP-Redirect...

See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/8827db0c-8f7c-4654-a3a8-cc99265f7649/does-azure-ad-support-backchannel-binding-for-saml-slo?forum=WindowsAzureAD

While "backchannel" would typically refer to SOAP requests I'm pretty sure there's no plan to support anything other than HTTP-Redirect.

Comment: Also... this has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178430/azure-ad-saml-single-logout-unsupported-binding-http-post?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Odd... I swear I think that had an answer *at one point*. Glad this helped!